# Auto increment issue on MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table (table_name on this example) with a column named id_table_name, which is `AUTO_INCREMENT`

All of a sudden, my application tried to add a row there, just like it was always doing, and it didn't work:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table_name(timestamp,referrer_ip) VALUES (1399299504.5109,'189.18.200.74');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '**153849251**' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Then, I searched for this value at the primary key, and didn't find it:

```
mysql> select * from table_name where id_table_name = **153849251**;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The last row on this table really had the ID 153849250, but for some reason this table wasn't accepting any new rows with the next ID. So, to solve this error, I had to add another row "forcing" ID **153849252** (just +1). Then, after that, the same insert statement I was trying to execute before worked like a charm:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table_name(id_table_name,timestamp,referrer_ip) VALUES (153849252,1399299504.5109,'189.18.200.74');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO table_name(timestamp,referrer_ip) VALUES (1399299504.5109,'189.18.200.74');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

See that the "id_table_name" is the only primary key I have on this table:

```
mysql> desc table_name \G
************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field: id_table_name
   Type: int(11)
   Null: NO
    Key: PRI
Default: NULL
  Extra: auto_increment
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Field: timestamp
   Type: double(16,4)
   Null: NO
    Key: MUL
Default: NULL
  Extra:<br>
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Field: referrer_ip
   Type: varchar(40)
   Null: NO
    Key:
Default: NULL
  Extra:
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why wasn't MySQL "accepting" that ID, even though it didn't exist at the table? Did anyone ever see this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: select max(your primary_key_field) from your_table_name;
step 2: ALTER TABLE your_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value_u_got_from_step1 + 1;
you can put any value instead of 1 in step2... I think this may work...